# Java Inet6Address.getScopeId returns different value than the OS

Tags: java, linux

I wrote a little utility that prints adapter information, similar to ifconfig on Linux. It uses Inet6Address.getScopeId(). This is the output it produces:

```
wlp0s20f3:  flags=<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
        getafix.fritz.box
        inet4  192.168.188.43  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.188.255
        fe80:0:0:0:22e6:bd9d:f6cf:625e%wlp0s20f3
        inet6  FE80::22E6:BD9D:F6CF:625E  prefixlen 64  scopeid 2  <wlp0s20f3>
        Ethernet DC:41:A9:A0:B7:A7

lo: flags=<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING> mtu 65536
        localhost
        inet4  127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        localhost
        inet6  ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 1  <lo>
        Local Loopback
```

The scope id is 2 for the adapter and 1 for the loopback adapter. But when I run ifconfig (Ubuntu 22.04), I get:

```
wlp0s20f3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.188.43  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.188.255
        inet6 fe80::22e6:bd9d:f6cf:625e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether dc:41:a9:a0:b7:a7  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 183433  bytes 194827855 (194.8 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 66336  bytes 19686929 (19.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 229950  bytes 572171194 (572.1 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 229950  bytes 572171194 (572.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

ifconfig prints a different scope id and als a different scope name. It looks like the numbers I get using ip6.getScopeId() are matching the adapter index (derived via ip6.getScopedInterface().getIndex()). The name I get using ip6.getScopedInterface().getName() matches the actual adapter name.
Where does "link" and "host" come from?

Any ideas?

Comment: The scope itself is a 4-bit field, so Java appears to be strictly correct. The ifconfig report may be showing the byte that includes scope as the top 4 bits and the 4 flag bits as the low four. Such a byte is present in the bits of the address.